Pythonでテトリスを作っているのですが、画面端での移動の処理がうまくいきません。
テトリスを作っている途中です。以下のコードを組んで実行してみると、Zミノが右端にある状態で右矢印キーを押すと新たに正方形が出現してしまいます。これの解決方法がどうしてもわかりません。print文を使ってみたところ、やはりflagはaになっていないことが分かりました。なので画面右端で右矢印キーを押してもself.object及びGameBoardにはなにも干渉していないはずです。なのにどうして、前述のようなことが起きるのでしょうか？（コードは自分で書いているものであり参考にしているもの等はありません。）（VSCodeを利用しています。
import pygame
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.mixer import *
import sys
import random
import time
SCREEN = Rect(0,0,250,415)

class Tetoris(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,tetoris,GameBoard,screen):
        self.main_x = 5 
        self.main_y = 1
        self.direction = 0
        self.object = []
        self.update = self.start
    
    def start(self,GameBoard):
        self.mino_number = random.randint(0,6)
        self.update = self.move
    
    def draw(self,tetoris,GameBoard,screen):      
        self.object = []
        for y in range(0,4):
            for x in range(0,4):
                if tetoris[self.mino_number][self.direction][y][x] >0:
                    self.object.append([self.main_y + y, self.main_x + x, tetoris[self.mino_number][self.direction][y][x]])
        
        b = len(self.object)
        for i in range(0,b):
            GameBoard[self.object[i][0]][self.object[i][1]] = self.object[i][2]

        teto_color = [(0,0,0),(255,0,0),(255,224,32),(0,32,255),(96,255,128),(255,160,16),(160,32,255),(80,208,255)]
        for y in range(0,22):
            for x in range(0,10):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,teto_color[GameBoard[y][x]],(50+15*x,50+15*y,15,15))
    
    def move(self,GameBoard):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.Lmove(GameBoard)
                   
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.Rmove(GameBoard)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.Dmove(GameBoard)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.Umove()
    
    def Lmove(self,GameBoard):
        copy_board = GameBoard
        spea = self.object
        a = len(spea)
        flag = 0

        for i in range(0,a):
            if self.main_x >0 and copy_board[spea[i][0]][spea[i][1] -1] ==0:
                spea[i][1] -= 1
                copy_board[spea[i][0]][spea[i][1]] = spea[i][2]
                copy_board[spea[i][0]][spea[i][1] +1] = 0
                flag += 1
                
        if flag == a:
            flag = 0
            self.main_x -= 1
            spea = []
            copy_board = []
    
    def Rmove(self,GameBoard):
        copy_board = GameBoard
        spea = self.object
        a = len(spea)
        flag = 0
       
        for i in range(a-1,-1,-1):
                
            if spea[i][1] < 9 and copy_board[spea[i][0]][spea[i][1] + 1] == 0:
                spea[i][1] += 1
                copy_board[spea[i][0]][spea[i][1]] = spea[i][2]
                copy_board[spea[i][0]][spea[i][1] -1] = 0
                flag += 1           
        if flag == a:
            flag = 0
            self.main_x += 1
            spea = []
            copy_board = []
    
    def Dmove(self,GameBoard):
        copy_board = GameBoard
        spea = self.object
        a = len(spea)
        flag = 0

        for i in range(a-1,-1,-1):
            if spea[i][0] <21 and copy_board[spea[i][0]+1][spea[i][1] ] ==0:
                spea[i][0] += 1
                copy_board[spea[i][0]][spea[i][1]] = spea[i][2]
                copy_board[spea[i][0]-1][spea[i][1]] = 0
                flag += 1
                
        if flag == a:
            flag = 0
            self.main_y += 1
            spea = []
            copy_board = []  
    def Death(self,GameBoard):
        None

        
        
def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN.size)

    GameBoard = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
    
    tetorised = [[[[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                  [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                  [[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                  [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]],
                  
                  [[[2,2,0,0],[2,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                   [[2,2,0,0],[2,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                   [[2,2,0,0],[2,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                   [[2,2,0,0],[2,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]],
                   
                   [[[3,0,0,0],[3,3,3,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                    [[3,3,0,0],[3,0,0,0],[3,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                    [[3,3,3,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                    [[0,3,0,0],[0,3,0,0],[3,3,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]],
                    
                    [[[0,4,4,0],[4,4,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                     [[4,0,0,0],[4,4,0,0],[0,4,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                     [[0,4,4,0],[4,4,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                     [[4,0,0,0],[4,4,0,0],[0,4,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]],
                     
                     [[[0,0,5,0],[5,5,5,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                      [[5,0,0,0],[5,0,0,0],[5,5,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                      [[5,5,5,0],[5,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                      [[5,5,0,0],[0,5,0,0],[0,5,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]],
                      
                      [[[0,6,0,0],[6,6,6,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                       [[6,0,0,0],[6,6,0,0],[6,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                       [[6,6,6,0],[0,6,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                       [[0,6,0,0],[6,6,0,0],[0,6,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]],
                       
                       [[[7,0,0,0],[7,0,0,0],[7,0,0,0],[7,0,0,0]],
                        [[7,7,7,7],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                        [[7,0,0,0],[7,0,0,0],[7,0,0,0],[7,0,0,0]],
                        [[7,7,7,7],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]]]

    
    tetoris = Tetoris(tetorised,GameBoard,screen)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while (1):
        clock.tick(120)
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        tetoris.update(GameBoard)
        tetoris.Death(GameBoard)
        tetoris.draw(tetorised,GameBoard,screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


この辺に掲載されているプログラムや解説が何か参考になるかもしれませんね。Pygameを使ってテトリスを作った (Python), ayahito-saji/Tetris0814, Tutorial #4, rajatdiptabiswas/tetris-pygame, 初心者でも安心！Pythonでテトリスを作る10ステップ, 【コード解説】Pythonで100行テトリス風落ちゲー
